# How to delete taxonomy field?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, managed-metadata, site-column, taxonomy

I usually use SharePoint Manager 2013 in order to delete taxonomy fields, so I can delete the hidden note field along with it, i.e. a field called `Organization` and `Organization_0`. In my production environment, with 2 app and 2 WFE servers, the SharePoint manager is not listing up the web applications. Any ideas about what I could do here to make it list the web applications?

Since I cannot see the web applications in SP manager in order to delete the taxonomy fields, I thought about using Powershell to delete taxonomy fields. Here I need some scripting help on how to delete the hidden field along with the taxonomy field.

I am using SP 2013 on-prem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below the Code, it will delete the taxonomy field with hidden note field.
[Deleting Managed Metadata Fields via PowerShell](http://sanjaybhagia.com/deleting-metadata-fields-via-powershell/)

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

#Clears up the site columns for the management system
function CleanUpSiteColumns($siteColl, $group){

    $siteColumns = $siteColl.RootWeb.Fields | Where-Object{$_.Group -eq $group}
    foreach($siteColumn in $siteColumns)
    {
        $noteFieldId = $null

        Write-Host "Deleting " $siteColumn.Title

        #If it is a taxonomy field, get the id of the hidden note field
        if($siteColumn.GetType().Name -eq "TaxonomyField")
        {
            #TaxtField holds the Id of the hidden notes field            
            $noteFieldId = $siteColumn.TextField
        }

        #Delete the Site Column
        $siteColumn.Delete()
        #Write-Host $noteFieldId


        #If notes field is there, find it and delete it as well
        if($noteFieldId -ne $null)
        {
            $noteFields = $siteColl.RootWeb.Fields | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $noteFieldId }
            if($noteFields -ne $null)
            {
                #Find the column
                foreach($noteField in $noteFields)
                {
                    Write-Host "Deleting " $noteField.Title
                    $noteField.Delete()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## call the function

```
$siteCollection = Get-SPSite http://demo.sp2013.local

CleanUpSiteColumns $siteCollection "My Taxonomy Columns"
```